# Which known philosophers are firm determinists?

Tags: free-will, determinism

I'm aware of the compatibilist attitude by some philosophers, such as Hegel and Daniel Dennet. I am interested in some philosophers who are firm determinists (deny free will).

Comment: You'll have to be more specific, "free will" is too vague a term to mean much without elaboration. On many accounts Hegel and Dennet deny "free will", it is mostly a matter of verbiage. Wikipedia lists some names under ["hard determinism"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_determinism#In_history)

Comment: here is another way to ask: "which traditional philosophers happen to agree with [Sam Harris on free will](https://samharris.org/the-illusion-of-free-will/) ? (admitting he is not a conventionally recognized philosopher)

Comment: The linked text does not really explain Harris's use so you better explain it in the post. From what I can tell there isn't much difference between him and Dennett aside from choices in phrasing.

Comment: Actually there is quite a bit of difference between him and Dennet on free will. Dennet is a compatibilist and Harris is a hard determinist.

Comment: Yes, and the difference amounts to Dennett calling "free will" what Harris calls "no free will", and both explaining how we come to be misguided about the matter. To get somewhere describe your understanding of the difference in the post.

Comment: You might find an answer there https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/incompatibilism-arguments/

Answer (score 5):

Galen Strawson, Richard Double, Ted Honderich, Derek Pereboom, Saul Smilansky. For links to further on these, see 2nd paragraph [here](http://www.informationphilosopher.com/solutions/philosophers/strawsong/).

Comment: this web page is absolutely awesome. pure gold !